# prove that $\frac{2}{b(a+b)}+\frac{2}{c(b+c)}+\frac{2}{a(c+a)} \ge \frac{27}{(a+b+c)^2}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, contest-math, holder-inequality

> Prove that $$\frac{2}{b(a+b)}+\frac{2}{c(b+c)}+\frac{2}{a(c+a)} \ge \frac{27}{(a+b+c)^2},$$ where $a,b,c$ are positive reals.

After applying AM-GM I got
$$
\frac{2}{b(a+b)}+\frac{2}{c(b+c)}+\frac{2}{a(c+a)}
\ge \frac{36}{(a+b+c)^2+a^2+b^2+c^2},
$$
which is similar to original expression but not quite enough. Any hints??

Comment: Solved there https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h115200p654322

Comment: @Zwim thanks for reference but this problem was supposed to be solved by using am gm hm inequality,is there any way you know of??

Comment: Also, most users understand what am-gm is (arithmetic mean-geometric mean).  Is that what you need to use.

Comment: I want to share a bulldozer method (not necessarily pretty) that almost always works for these types of inequalities: Putting everything over a common denominator and WLOG setting $b=a+x$ and $c=b+y$ for some $x,y\geq0$ we get that the inequality is equivalent to $$72 a^4 \left(x^2-x y+y^2\right)+a^3 \left(80 x^3+51 x^2 y-3 x y^2+80 y^3\right)+a^2 \left(26 x^4+95 x^3 y+30 x^2 y^2+41 x y^3+26 y^4\right)+a \left(2 x^5+30 x^4 y+35 x^3 y^2+17 x^2 y^3+12 x y^4+2 y^5\right)+2 x^2 y (x+y)^3\geq0$$ which is obviously true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Holder $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2}{b(a+b)}=\frac{1}{(a+b+c)^2}\sum_{cyc}b\sum_{cyc}(a+b)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{b(a+b)}\geq\frac{27}{(a+b+c)^2}.$$